# Bug in math program

Tags: python-2.7, math

could you kind people please tell me why this program fails on my final submit to codewars every time, I can't seem to figure it out. They don't even provide the actual string that failed so I'm left just trying all sorts of different combinations which have all worked perfectly well so far. I don't mean to cheat or anything but I'm frankly quite frustrated and didn't really know what else to do.

The program is basically supposed to scan a list of 'people' with single 25, 50 or 100 dollar bills in the order of the list and calculate whether it has enough change to sell them all a movie ticket. The ticket costs 25 dollars. The program does not have any money or change to begin with, so it basically has to work with what it gets from the line. If the entire line can be processed the program should return a string "YES", otherwise "NO".

So for example, [25, 25, 50, 100] should return a yes, etc...

Here's my code -

```
def tickets(x):
    t = 0
    f = 0
    h = 0
    lst = []

    for i in x:
        if i==25:
            t+=1
            lst.append('c')
        elif i==50:
            if t>=1:
                t-=1
                f+=1
                lst.append('c')
            else:
                lst.append('u')



        elif i == 100:
            if t>=3:
                t-=3
                h+=100
            elif f>=1 and t>=1:
                f-=1
                t-=1
                lst.append('c')
            else:
                lst.append('u')


    if 'u' not in lst:
        return "YES"

    else:
        return "NO"
```

Any help in identifying the bug would be appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: The first suggestion would be to use meaningful names for variables. `lst`, `t` or `f` conveys nothing about the variable in the context of the program which makes it a lot harder to read and understand.

Comment: if someone has a hundred and you hold 3 twenty-fives and a 50, do not give away all your 25's. Give them a 50 and a 25 and keep your 25s for if the next person hands you a 50. in the i==100, switch your if and elif. Also to be consistent when you give change for 100 with three twenty fives (aside: there are no 25 dollar bills, at least not US $) you ought to add C to your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will fail on 25,25,25, 25, 50,100,50 because you give the person with the 100 all your 25s, and then you cannot help the final 50. Give the 100 a 50 and a 25 and you will be able to help the last person with the 50. Flip the order of

```
if t>=3:
            t-=3
            h+=100
            lst.append('c')
        elif f>=1 and t>=1:
            f-=1
            t-=1
            lst.append('c')
```

to

```
        if f>=1 and t>=1:
            f-=1
            t-=1
            lst.append('c')
         elif t>=3:
            t-=3
            h+=100
            lst.append('c')
```

and I bet it passes.